# Correct syntax to use near '%s' error while selecting data using Python from MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql

Running this code

```
res = cursor.execute("SELECT `password` FROM `players` WHERE `username` = %s", usern)
```

I get this error:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1

Comment: Learn to use parameters and never have a problem like this again!

Comment: Are you sure that's the right [paramstyle](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) for the library you're using?

Comment: sql = """SELECT password FROM `players`
             WHERE `username` = %s
          """
    res = cursor.execute(sql, usern)
    print (res) gives me same error

Comment: replace comma with '%', like **"SELECT `password` FROM `players` WHERE `username` = %s" % usern**

Comment: or you should use tuple : execute("...", (usern))

Answer (score 3):

The parametrized queries expect a tuple as an argument:

```
query = """SELECT `password` FROM `players` WHERE `username` = %s"""
res = cursor.execute(query, (usern, ))
```

Comment: Note that's *not* a tuple.

Comment: Why not? Tuple can have only one member.

Comment: They can indeed, but *that's not the syntax for it*. The *comma* is the important part of the tuple, a one-tuple looks like `(value,)`.